# Нужно ли выделять запятыми сравнительный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация

...со сквозными расточками полублоков цилиндров с крышками на них и прокладками как у автомобильных...

Comment: Совет. Приводите фразу целиком. Еще лучше: одну две предыдущих, т. н. "контекст". От этого часто зависит ответ на ваши вопросы. Вот здесь как раз тот случай. Без контекста непонятно, что имел в виду автор: обычный ли тут сравнительный оборот (тогда он естественно, требует обособления) или нечто иное. Скорее первое, но наверняка не берусь утверждать, а гадать не хочется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...со сквозными расточками полублоков цилиндров с крышками на них и
>   прокладками как у автомобильных...

Запятая перед ***как*** однозначно нужна.

**P.S.**

Лучше было бы, если бы Вы, **Alenka**, привели предложение полностью, а не кусок из него. Возможно, помимо указанной запятой будут нужны и другие пунктуационные знаки.

Comment: Там предложение совершенно безумное, но знаков других, похоже. не понадобится. Нужно только выделить сравнительный оборот с двух сторон.

Answer (score 0):

Смысл не очень понятен, здесь может быть два решения:

1) имеются прокладки, как и у... (обособленное сравнение);

2) прокладки такого типа (нет обособления, назван определяющий признак).